# arc length on circle

Tags: calculus, integration

http://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/how-do-the-power-series-definitions-of-sin-and-cos-relate-to-their-geometrical-interpretations/#more-5401

I need an explanation of this bit on the blog:

One non-rigorous but informative way of thinking about this is that for each $t$ between $x$ and $1$, we should take an interval $[x,x+dt]$, work out the length of the bit of the circle vertically above this interval, and sum up all those lengths. The bit of the circle in question is a straight line (since $dt$ is infinitesimally small) and by similar triangles its length is $\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$.

How did I write that down? Well, the big triangle I was thinking of was one with vertices $(0,0), (t,0)$ and the point on the circle directly above $(t,0)$, which is $(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$, by Pythagoras’s theorem. The little triangle has one side of length $dt$, which corresponds to the side in the big triangle of length $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. So the hypotenuse of the little triangle is$ \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$, as I claimed.

Comment: specifically why does dt correspond to sqrt(1-t^2) ? and why for each t between x and 1, we should take an interval [x,x+dt]?

Comment: It should read $[t,t+dt]$.

Comment: i thought so. But how do you show the similarity of triangles? and also why for each t between x and 1? if you do that wouldnt you be 'overlapping' the triangles?

Comment: for example take [0.5, 0.5+dt], then next you take [0.50001, 0.50001+dt] like that?

Answer (score 3):

> why does $dt$ correspond to $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ ?

The big (right) triangle $\triangle OPQ$ is [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles) to the little (right) triangle $\triangle SPR$, because by construction the side $PQ$ is  perpendicular to the side $PR$ and the side $OP$ is perpendicular to the side $PS$ *as* $S$ *tends to* $P$. These triangles have two identical angles, and thus three identical ones. $\angle OPQ=\angle RPS$ and $\angle OQP=\angle SRP$, as shown in the picture, where the $x$-coordinates of $P$ and $S$ are, respectively,  $t$ and $t+dt$.  As such corresponding sides have lengths in the same ratio: $$\dfrac{PR}{PQ}=\dfrac{PS}{OP}.$$

Since $OP=1$, $PQ=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ and $PR=dt$, the infinitesimally small length $ds$ of the arc of circle between $P$ and $S$ is given by  $$ds=PS=\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

> why for each $t$ between $x$ and $1$?

Because one is evaluating the length of the arc from the *generic* point $P$ whose $x,y$-coordinates are $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$ to the point whose coordinates are $(1,0)$. This length is (see the [original post](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/how-do-the-power-series-definitions-of-sin-and-cos-relate-to-their-geometrical-interpretations/#more-5401))

$$\int_x^1\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

[image]

ADDED: If you apply the [arc length formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating)

\begin{equation*}
s=\int_{x}^{1}\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{dy}{dt}\right) ^{2}}dt
\end{equation*}

to the function $y=\sqrt{1-t^{2}}$, since $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$ you get the same result as above

\begin{equation*}
s=\int_{x}^{1}\sqrt{1+\left( -\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\right) ^{2}}
dt=\int_{x}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}}dt=\int_{x}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}
}}.
\end{equation*}

ADDED 2. For further information on the derivation and application of the arc length formula see [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx).

Comment: u missed an equal sign. ps/op=

Comment: @jim It is a blank space, because I intended to show in the picture that $\dfrac{PR}{PQ}=\dfrac{PS}{OP}$ implies $\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\dfrac{PS}{1}$, since $PR=dt$, $PQ=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ and $OP=1$, as explained in the answer.

Comment: I am new to integration so my question is usually I think of integration as an area. You give the function in 2 dimensions and the integral gives you the area underneath it. But here the integral gives the length of the curve not area. I find this unusual and curious?

Comment: And in the case of area it is somewhat intuitively clear how we get the area from adding up rectangular 'blocks' under the curve. Is there supposed to be an analogous description here for length?

Comment: In this case we can say that the "infinitesimal" length is $\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$. In general see e.g. [Finding arc lengths by integrating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating).

Comment: is there such a thing as integral of ds? what is the meaning of this?

Comment: $ds$ is an *infinitesimal* or *elementary* arc length and $s$ is the total lenght of the arc from $a$ to $b$. $s=\int_a^bds$. From the Wikipedia: *(...) an infinitesimal part of the curve $ds$ (or consider this as a limit in which the change in $s$ approaches $ds$).*

Comment: You can start by considering a finite sum of the lengths of $n$  line segments inscribed in the curve and then apply a limiting process to the sum, where $n$ tends to infinity. This converts the sum into a definite integral. In each line segment you can apply the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: See these note http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx